# How to trim the image after rotating?

Tags: image, animation

[image]

Want to rotate this image and then trim it.
 consider

```
image=R6UgC.jpg;
Imrot=Rotate[image, 2 Degree];
ImageTrim[Imrot, {{560, 400}, {900, 900}}]
```

getting error
    ImageTrim::imginv: Expecting an image or graphics instead...

Comment: Use `ImageRotate` instead of `Rotate`. `Rotate` works on Graphics primitives and objects and returns a Graphics primitive or objects with head `Rotate`.

Comment: @Sjoerd Post that as an answer or I shall close as "simple mistake."

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Should the mere existence of an answer invalidate the "simple mistake" closing reason? (seriously)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one more question...How to enhanced the image quality or intensity.

Comment: @belisarius No... I expect this would likely be closed either way; I was giving Sjoerd a change to answer if he wanted to.  I suppose in hindsight that could seem like favoritism but rather I thought that possibly the answer would be slightly less trivial than the comment and that *maybe* it could stay open for that reason.

Comment: @santosh That is an entirely separate question; post it as such.  But please make the question as clear as possible.  ("Improve image quality" is very vague.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ah, OK. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Posted an answer. Not sure whether the above counts as a "simple mistake" although `ImageRotate` was listed under "See also" on the `Rotate` help page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ImageRotate` instead of `Rotate`. `Rotate` works on Graphics primitives and objects and returns a Graphics primitive or objects with head `Rotate`.

```
(* with ImageRotate increased angle for illustrative purposes *)
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6UgC.jpg"];
Imrot = ImageRotate[image, 20 Degree];
ImageTrim[Imrot, {{560, 400}, {900, 900}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See the difference:

```
Rotate[image, 20 Degree]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Head@Rotate[image, 20 Degree]
```

> Rotate

```
Head@Imrot
```

> Image